# Unknown IntegrityError in Django

Tags: python, django

I have this small project to create my bills through `Django` and `Latex` which worked flawlessly until today. Now when I try to add another costumer, `Django` throws

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "kunden_kundearbeitsamt_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(4) already exists.
```

---

These are the model definitions in question:

```
class Kunde(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length = 200)
    vorname = models.CharField('Vorname', max_length = 200)
    geburtsdatum = models.DateField('Geburtsdatum', max_length = 200)
    untersuchungsdatum = models.DateField('Untersuchungsdatum', max_length = 200)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class KundeArbeitsamt(Kunde):
    kundennummer = models.CharField('Kundennummer', max_length = 100)
    bglnummer = models.CharField('BGL-Nummer', max_length = 100)
    empfaenger = models.ForeignKey('rechnungen.NumberToEmpfaenger', blank = True, null = True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Proband Arbeitsamt"
        verbose_name_plural = "Proband Arbeitsamt"

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}, {}'.format(self.name, self.vorname)
```

---

The admin part where the object is created (nothing special, I guess):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import KundeArbeitsamt

class KundeArbeitsamtAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ('name',)

admin.site.register(KundeArbeitsamt, KundeArbeitsamtAdmin)
```

I swear, I did not make any migrations or other changes to the database (Postgres) whatsoever. `Django` is handling the creation of the objects. What is causing this error and how to fix it?

Comment: which database is behind that?

Comment: What's the code to create the object? Are you manually setting the id or letting Django handle that?

Comment: @kichik: Django, updated the question. That's all the code there is to the model.

Comment: I would start with looking on the table, figuring out the content and afterwards figuring out why the hell django wants set an already use ID. On postgres check the corresponding sequence for their next value.

Comment: Can you include the code where you use the model to create the object?

Comment: @dahrens: And how? I mean it used to work a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is raised by your database, because django wants to add an new column with an ID (`=4`) already in use.

To investigate further you need to find the part of your app responsible for creating the IDs. Django usually delegates this task to your database. In case of postgres the datatype [`serial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) is used. Postgres uses so called sequences for this purpose and generates and executes the following SQL for you:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
);
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
```

I would now start with checking the database sanity like that:

```
-- views contents of the table
SELECT * FROM kunden_kundearbeitsamt;
-- check the sequence
select currval('kunden_kundearbeitsamt_id_seq');
```

If the first shows 4 records with IDs 1, 2, 3 and 4 and the sequence answers with 4 everything is alright. I would proceed with the django sources to figure out why they pass an ID on object creating without relying on the sequence. The django shell might be a good place to start with in that case.

Otherwise I would fix the sequence and ask myself how this happend as it is barely the case that postgres makes mistakes at this point.

```
SELECT setval('kunden_kundearbeitsamt_id_seq', (SELECT max(id) FROM kunden_kundearbeitsamt));
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the background info. I ended up using `SELECT setval('kunden_kundearbeitsamt_id_seq', (SELECT max(id) FROM kunden_kundearbeitsamt));` to change the value of the sequence.

Comment: I've added your solution to the answer.

Comment: I remember having inserted entries via `Postico` which might have caused the error. Thanks again for this good answer and keep up the good work!